# Bash script to loop through output from AWS Command Line Client

Tags: bash, loops, aws-cli, amazon-ec2

I'm getting a list of EC2 instances and then trying to loop through them but for some reason I'm not able to get the loop to work.

`output="$(aws ec2 describe-instances --filters 'Name=tag:Environment,Values=development' --query '[Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicDnsName]' --output text)"`

`echo $output` displays something like:

```
ec2-55-55-555-555.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
ec2-66-66-666-666.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Then I create an array like this:

```
instances=(${output//'\n'/ })
```

`echo ${instances[0]}` and `echo ${instances[1]}` gives the correct output.

And then try to iterate through the array:

`for i in $instances; do echo instance: "$i"; done`

But I get:

instance: ec2-55-55-555-555.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
ec2-66-66-666-666.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

Instead of:

```
instance: ec2-55-55-555-555.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
instance: ec2-66-66-666-666.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

What am I doing wrong? And is there a better way to loop through the results, maybe rather using the json output format?

Comment: Try to run `for i in $output; do echo $i; done`

Comment: I've tried that, it echos the whole variable. Doesn't split the lines.

Comment: what about: `for i in "${instances[@]}"; do ...`?

Comment: Just add a line separator with: `for i in $instances; do echo instance: "$i"$'\n'; done`

Comment: Also see [Bash FAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for how to properly read line-by-line from a stream.

Comment: This works on my mac but not on my Codeship builds: `echo $output | while read line ; do echo instance: $line ; done`

Comment: On Codeship $output was space separated, anyone know why? I added `tr ' ' '\n'` and now its working

Answer (score 25):

I am not sure if you got an answer for this question. Will this help?

```
for dns in $(aws ec2 describe-instances --region ap-northeast-1 --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicDnsName' --output text) ; do echo $dns ; done
```

Comment: How can we do this with multiple columns?

Answer (score 1):

For windows cli:

aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId" > instances

FOR /f %i IN (instances) DO aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids %i

Comment: The question asks for a bash script

Comment: But useful. Vote up.

Answer (score 1):

This also works for me, add it to a bash array:

```
for instance in $(aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Application,Values=yourValue" "Name=tag:Environment,Values=development" --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceId' --output text); do envInstances+=(${instance}); done

for i in ${envInstances[@]}; do echo "hello $i"; done

hello i-instance1
hello i-instance12
hello i-instance16
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you just gave up, but in BASH, better to just do this:

> OUTPUT=($(aws ec2 describe-instances --filters
> 'Name=tag:Environment,Values=development' --query
> '[Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicDnsName]' --output text))

then (if you want a count)

> echo "${#OUTPUT[@]} instances found."

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

One liner using `xargs`:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters 'Name=tag:Environment,Values=development' --query '[Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicDnsName]' --output text | xargs --no-run-if-empty -n1 echo 'Instance:'
```